# How to simulate CSMA/CD protocol in ns3?

Tags: c++, networking, ns-3

I'm trying to simulate the CSMA/CD protocol using ns3 software for a course project. However, after installing ns3, I've checked the official documentation and asked the teaching assistant, but I couldn't find specific implementation details.

I even saw some answers stating that ns3 does not support simulating collision detection and backoff logic. Is this true? If not, how can I implement the CSMA/CD protocol in ns3?